# How do I manage this difficult stakeholder?

Tags: communication, management, project-management

I need to send an update every week on a turn-around initiative to senior management and the working group.

There's a bully in the working group who waits for me to send an update highlighting that her task is "at risk" and then replies-all saying my update is inaccurate because her team actually fixed it (it's not fixed and she blatantly lies about it). No one stands up to her because she's so aggressive.

What can I do to protect myself and stop "taking the bait"?

Comment: How do you arrive at the conclusion that it is "at risk"?

Comment: What is the metric/test that determines if her task is 'fixed'? Make sure you're on the same page about that, then illustrate how you're testing it and then the outcome. I expect that at least one (reasonable) person will come away from that process with a new understanding what they should do next.

Comment: Hmmm - you probably need to add a bit more info - are you sure that the task really is "at risk"? And if so, then presumably you have some proof to show that it's not complete (or she can't provide proof that it *is*). How do you know she is "waiting" for you to send the update? It might be she is just reacting to your incorrect (in her opinion) assertion that it's at risk, which is has now gone to the senior management making her look bad. Do you ask people the status of their tasks before you send the update?

Comment: > who waits for me to send an update highlighting that her task is “at risk” and then replies  

You say she is waiting for you to give your update before contradicting you. What chances do you give you her assessment of the situation for you to include in the report?

Comment: How are you "taking the bait"?

Comment: Downvoted for not answering relevant questions in the comments. Impossible to answer properly without appropriate context.

Answer (score 76):

You are aggregating reports from a number of people into a summary report. Consistently, when you report that one person's tasks are not where they should be, this person replies to everyone saying "well they are now!" and this annoys you. Partly because you're not sure it's true, and partly because it feels like the person is contradicting you or arguing with you. Yes?

When I get reports that tell me 6 out of 7 areas are fine and one is not, and I consistently get updates that "it's fixed!" from the 7th, this doesn't make me feel that the summarizer is wrong. It makes me think that 7th person is just scraping by, and if it wasn't for the accurate summaries driving these just in time fixes, we would be in worse trouble. I'm a sunny and positive person. Some people might exist who would think "I wonder why Anthea invented a problem for that 7th person, is she trying to make the 7th person look bad?"

If you reply defending your summary as accurate, and arguing with person 7, you risk shifting more people into the "maybe Anthea and 7 are feuding" camp. If you feel you must reply to the "inaccurate" accusation, try something like:

> Glad to hear that [issue] is no longer a risk for the project. I'll reflect that in the next summary. Thanks for the update.

After several incidents, you might switch from a cheerful "we're all in this together tone" to issue a reminder that some other mechanism exists for these updates and reply-all to the summary-readers isn't it. This is delicate and requires care, so don't do it if you're not confident in your ability to stick up for the summary-readers rather than lecture person 7. Something like

> I saw your update in [normal mechanism] already and will be including it in the next summary. Let's keep email traffic on this summary only to things that can't be represented in [normal mechanism] since a lot of stakeholders are receiving these emails.

If you're not already including "proof" (charts, graphs, links) in your summary, it might not hurt to start doing so. Be sure to include timestamps when you do. "Number of outstanding tickets, Friday 10am" sort of thing. Whether 7's issue is that [normal mechanism] is out of date when you pull from it, leading you to conclude some things aren't done, or that 7's team rushes around dealing with things you've highlighted in the summary, "receipts" (as the younguns say) tell the story.

Comment: Add in the sources of data. OP isn't fabricating the summary out of thin air... people in authority are behind it. If you say "Progress Summary (Dept A, Mr. Manager)", then for the bully to counter that, they're now challenging Mr. Manager, not you.

Comment: If you want to be passive aggressive make sure to get the latest updates for the problem area right before you send out the summary or double check it right before you send out the summary. 'Has this changed in the last 30 minutes' might get them to shut up about it.

Answer (score 45):

Generally speaking, make sure that everyone knows what you are reporting on.

There are two ways to go about this: either teams self-report, or you have a designated system where teams deploy to, and another group, lets call them QA, sets their seal of approval how they see fit.

Either way, if you write an email, that obviously has to go out at a certain point, you have to prepare it, so you need to include a date. For example "Progress Report on Project X, Friday 13th 10am". Obviously, this mail will go out later than 10am, since you need time to prepare it.

If the issue was reported fixed before that date, this is indeed your fault. You need to work on that.

If not, stay constructive and on point:

> That is great. Make sure to (self-report it)/(deploy it to the system and have QA report it) in time for next weeks update and I will include in the next email!

Whether she lies about it or not is not your problem (I guess...). You reported the facts. And fact is, that it had not passed the quality gate you reported on, and you will include it once it does.

Comment: Pretty much this. I would also make sure that this self-reporting has a known deadline. So, you can give a report of the status as of a certain time, e.g., 10 AM. Should something actually be fixed between that time and sending out the report, it is clear to the person who fixed it that the fix is not in the report.

Comment: Agreed, many answers are taking the one side of this which we've heard very credulously. Without prior warning of the report (and shared definition of done) how else would anyone react? Attacking someone publicly and then complaining about their self-defence is classic cry-bully. I wonder what all the deleted comments under the question said

Comment: I am not sure how you make "an update every week" into some sort of sneaky ninja surprise sprung unto an unsuspecting victim without warning. If anything, it sounds incredibly boring, repetitive and predictable. "All" the deleted comments were exactly 5, who should put their answer in an answer, not in a comment. They are still free to do so. "Don't answer in comments" isn't exactly a surprise to anybody either.

Answer (score 18):

A solution I used for this was to include the date and hour of when the status of a task was read.

For example:

---

### Task B

Updated at 2024-01-16 14:05

Status: At Risk

Larger description about the task and your other report info about it.

---

This way it doesn't matter if someone corrects you or not on the status of the task. As of the time of the report elaboration, it was at the specific status, and that's all that matters.

If you have to call someone on the phone to get a status, stop doing that.
Ask the status by e-mail, message system or some other "*by writing*" system, and save a print of the reports folks gave you.

If someone doesn't send you the message/e-mail about the task status, then place the status as "unknown", and put a note that the task's status didn't get an status update by the deadline of the report.

Corporate bullies are rather weak when it comes to *following processes*. If you make a process that shields yourself from those "mistakes", you'll solve most of your problems.

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy answer to this situation. The person reporting that X is fixed may be operating on the concept that action was taken on X which means that everything is fine. Unfortunately, often that only means that some action was taken, not that correct action was taken. Nor does it mean that the action taken doesn't cause other problems. Often it certainly means that proper analysis was skipped, and a deeper problem was simply covered over.

Ultimately, this is a problem for upper management to fix. Simply keep documenting that this person's team is not measuring up to the rest of the working group. Private discussions with the manager over all of them might help your case but document the situation well. Over time, it will become obvious that the way that team is operating does not match the rest of the working group and the manager is the cause.

(A client had this exact situation, and it took a while before the manager over that group was fired. A problem would be reported in a meeting, he would text someone to fix it right away, and then report in that meeting that the problem was fixed. It just was that every meeting reported problems. Things never stabilized.)

Answer (score 2):

First, you should seek to resolve this in a **private** conversation with her. Her reaction was not warranted from your point of view, so this should be resolved between only the two of you. Continuing the discussion in group exchange would frame *you* as the bully trying to pick a fight instead of resolving the issue.

An aggressive reaction tells the person does not feel safe to respond in a civil way. They believe bad things would happen to them because you don't respect them as a person (they might suspect you enjoy showing them in bad light), or you just don't care about their interests. As a base for any discussion to continue, **safety** has to be created first.

**Respect** would be quite hard to fake. Try considering the possibility they are a rational well-meaning person whose situation you don't fully understand yet. Maybe they were mislead by a team member? Then you can sincerely start the conversation with unbiased facts, like

> Hi, looks like we had a different view on the status of task X. I gathered my data from system Z, do you have any idea why the correct status was not reflected there?

Ensuring **mutual purpose** is the other important component of safety, letting the other person know you want situation to be better for both of you, not advancing only your own agenda. This could be expressed by contrasting their possible fears against your actual intent, such as

> I'm not looking for ways to blame you or your team. We need our management to have objective information, so they know which teams could take on more work and which teams need more resources. Could this be something we work on together to achieve?

Addressing these concerns should let her feel safe to suggest how they could provide timely accurate information for your next reports. Her team knows where the problem lies, so they are in best position to solve it.

Recommended reading: "Crucial accountability" by K. Patterson, J. Grenny, R. McMillan, A. Switzler and D. Maxfield.

Comment: "An aggressive reaction tells the person does not feel safe to respond in a civil way" - or that they're a jerk, of course

Answer (score 2):

You want your report to be accurate and you don't want to get into a messy fight.

Focus on the former by being more precise. Add something like this to the introduction of your report:

> "According to the status updates
> available to me on (day) at (time), the current project status is as
> follows:"

This allows you to treat anything that's coming as a response to your report as an input of data, while at the same time having no need to update your report - that information was, in fact, not available to you at the stated date and time.

You can be a bit more passive-aggressive by sending out a reminder a day or two before the report to everyone asking for up-to-date status information so you can include it in the report.

If everyone gets that mail, and then 2 days later you send out the report and the troublesome person sends one of their "but it's fixed now!" responses, all the other recipients will realize that one of two things must be true: Either troublesome person didn't give you the requested status update, or troublesome person fixed the thing just then.

The second line of defense can be (you don't include details on how the report is written) to explicitly state the sources for information contained in your report. If, as an example, you have a table listing all the project parts, their current status and estimated completion date, simply add a source column and if your troublesome person says that X is done, list it in the next report as done with them as the source of that information. This way, if it turns out that X is not, in fact, done, the hammer falls on them, not you.
Of course, this assumes that your job is simply compiling the report, not checking it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's some legitimate disagreement on whether the tasks are 'at risk', I would likely ignore this person.  If they escalate the conflict, present your reasons for marking it as at risk in a clear dispassionate way.  Do not make it personal, no matter how much they bother you.  If your only responsibility is to report the facts, do that.  It's someone else's responsibility to deal with the risks that you are reporting.

If it's any consolation, you are already annoying/punishing this person by pointing out a reality they don't want exposed. A calm, unruffled demeanor will only amplify that. They want you to get in a fight where they can egg you on and get you to do or say something stupid so they can make that the focus and not their failings.